# The result of dataframe.mean() is incorrect

Tags: python, dataframe, mean

I am workint in Python 2.7 and I have a data frame and I want to get the average of the column called 'c', but only the rows that verify that the values in another column are equal to some value.
When I execute the code, the answer is unexpected, but when I execute the calculation, calculating the median, the result is correct.

Why is the output of the mean incorrect?

The code is the following:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([['A', 1, 2, 3], ['A', 4, 5, np.nan], ['A', 7, 8, 9], ['B', 3, 2, np.nan], ['B', 5, 6, np.nan], ['B',5, 6, np.nan]]), 
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
)
```

```py
df
mean1 = df[df.a == 'A'].c.mean()
mean2 = df[df.a == 'B'].c.mean()

median1 = df[df.a == 'A'].c.median()
median2 = df[df.a == 'B'].c.median()
```

The output:

```py
df
Out[1]: 
   a  b  c    d
0  A  1  2    3
1  A  4  5  nan
2  A  7  8    9
3  B  3  2  nan
4  B  5  6  nan
5  B  5  6  nan
```

```py
mean1
Out[2]: 86.0

mean2
Out[3]: 88.66666666666667

median1
Out[4]: 5.0

median2
Out[5]: 6.0
```

It is obvious that the output of the mean is incorrect.

Thanks.

Comment: Your columns are dtype `object`, it is doing string concatenation then dividing, this has to be unintended...

Comment: @yatu the median of [2,6,6] is 6, it's correct, but the average of [2,6,6] is not 86.6.

Comment: Please change the last line of you post 'It is obvious that the output of the media is incorrect.' from media to mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandas is doing string concatenation for the "sum" when calculating the mean, this is plain to see from your example frame.

---

```
>>> df[df.a == 'B'].c
3    2
4    6
5    6
Name: c, dtype: object
>>> 266 / 3
88.66666666666667
```

If you look at the `dtype`'s for your DataFrame, you'll notice that all of them are `object`, even though no single `Series` contains mixed types.  This is due to the declaration of your `numpy` array.   Arrays are not meant to contain heterogenous types, so the array defaults to dtype `object`, which is then passed to the DataFrame constructor.  You can avoid this behavior by passing the constructor a list instead, which can hold differing `dtype`'s with no issues.

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['A', 1, 2, 3], ['A', 4, 5, np.nan], ['A', 7, 8, 9], ['B', 3, 2, np.nan], ['B', 5, 6, np.nan], ['B',5, 6, np.nan]],
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
)

df[df.a == 'B'].c.mean()
```

```
4.666666666666667
```

---

```
In [17]: df.dtypes
Out[17]:
a     object
b      int64
c      int64
d    float64
dtype: object
```

---

I still can't imagine that this behavior is intended, so I believe it's worth opening an issue report on the pandas development page, but in general, you shouldn't be using `object` dtype Series for numeric calculations.